# Как растянуть градиент во весь экран?

Tags: css

Подскажите где ошибка?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
body {
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #abdcff, #0396ff) no-repeat;
}

.stylemenu {
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* При наведении меняет цвет в меню*/

.stylemenu a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 73px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}


/* меню при наведении меняет цвет*/

.two,
.five,
.eight,
.eleven {
  background: rgba(0, 228, 246, .4);
}

.framemenu:hover {
  background: rgba(176, 176, 176, 0.67);
}

.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 23px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 7px;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 4px 5px black);
  color: #723232;
  margin-left: 153px;
}

.classmenu {
  background: #edf6ff;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #ff761a;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

b.ckgroundfon {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы `body` занял всю высоту экрана, укажите ему следующее свойство:

```
height: 100vh;
```

или

```
min-height 100vh;
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
body {
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #abdcff, #0396ff) no-repeat;
}

.stylemenu {
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* При наведении меняет цвет в меню*/

.stylemenu a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 73px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}


/* меню при наведении меняет цвет*/

.two,
.five,
.eight,
.eleven {
  background: rgba(0, 228, 246, .4);
}

.framemenu:hover {
  background: rgba(176, 176, 176, 0.67);
}

.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 23px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 7px;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 4px 5px black);
  color: #723232;
  margin-left: 153px;
}

.classmenu {
  background: #edf6ff;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #ff761a;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

b.ckgroundfon {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: @Артем, если еще нужна поддержка древних браузеров https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units используйте совместно с JS. Вот пример на jQuery `$('body').css('height', $( window ).height());`

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #abdcff, #0396ff) no-repeat;
}
```